# MySQL Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I've tested my query using online tool but to no avail. Im stuck;
http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

Here is my code;

```
SELECT Replace(Replace(Replace(Mid( 
                                              Substring_index( 
               node_data_field_pdf_download.field_pdf_download_data, 
                               ':"', 
                       3), 30), '";s:3', ''), ':', ''), '"', '') AS 
       language, 
       files.filepath 
       AS filepath 
FROM   node 
       LEFT JOIN content_field_pdf_download node_data_field_pdf_download 
              ON node.vid = node_data_field_pdf_download.vid 
       LEFT JOIN files files 
              ON files.fid = node_data_field_pdf_download.field_pdf_download_fid 
WHERE  ( node.status = 1 ) 
       AND ( node.type IN ( 'codeofconduct' ) )
```

I've tried using escape character but the result is still the same. I've tested the query above on phpMyAdmin 2.11.7 , it worked just fine.

It render error when I tried to use it with php codes. The complete codes is below;

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
<select class="neutral" id="type" name="type" onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"> <?php
$sql = "SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MID(SUBSTRING_INDEX(node_data_field_pdf_download.field_pdf_download_data, ':\"', 3),30),'";s:3',''),':',''),'\"','') AS language, 
 files.filepath AS filepath FROM node
 LEFT JOIN content_field_pdf_download node_data_field_pdf_download ON node.vid = node_data_field_pdf_download.vid
 LEFT JOIN files files ON files.fid = node_data_field_pdf_download.field_pdf_download_fid
 WHERE (node.status = 1) AND (node.type in ('codeofconduct'))";

$result = db_query($sql);

echo '<option value="" disabled selected>-- Please select --</option>';

while($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
   $filepath[] = $new_array['filepath'];
   echo '<option value="'.$row['filepath'].'">'.$row['language'].'</option>';

}
```

?>

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: show your full syntax error ?

Comment: apparently this produces error:                                  SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MID(SUBSTRING_INDEX(node_data_field_pdf_download.field_pdf_download_data, ':\"', 3),30),'";s:3',''),':',''),'\"','') AS language, 
  files.filepath AS filepath FROM node
  LEFT JOIN content_field_pdf_download node_data_field_pdf_download ON node.vid = node_data_field_pdf_download.vid
  LEFT JOIN files files ON files.fid = node_data_field_pdf_download.field_pdf_download_fid
  WHERE (node.status = 1) AND (node.type in ('codeofconduct'))

Comment: you can try paste the codes into http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is

```
(node_data_field_pdf_download.field_pdf_download_data, ':\"', 3),30),'";s:3',''),':','')
                                                                      ^ here
```

use `\` before `"`

try this

```
$sql = "SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MID(SUBSTRING_INDEX(node_data_field_pdf_download.field_pdf_download_data, ':\"', 3),30),'\"s:3',''),':',''),'\"','') AS language, 
 files.filepath AS filepath FROM node
 LEFT JOIN content_field_pdf_download node_data_field_pdf_download ON node.vid = node_data_field_pdf_download.vid
 LEFT JOIN files files ON files.fid = node_data_field_pdf_download.field_pdf_download_fid
 WHERE (node.status = 1) AND (node.type in ('codeofconduct'))";
```